# Elasticsearch JAR hell error

Tags: elasticsearch, java

I created a Java file using Elasticsearch Java API. in NetBeans, everything worked just fine.

However, I started getting the following error:

```
org/elasticsearch/plugins/PluginsService.java:342:in `loadBundles': java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to load bundle [file:/D:/ELK-2.0/elasticsearch-2.0.0/plugins/license/license-2.0.0.jar, file:/D:/ELK-2.0/elasticsearch-2.0.0/plugins/license/license-core-2.0.0.jar, file:/D:/ELK-2.0/elasticsearch-2.0.0/plugins/license/license-plugin-api-2.0.0.jar, file:/D:/ELK-2.0/elasticsearch-2.0.0/plugins/marvel-agent/marvel-agent-2.0.0.jar] due to jar hell
        from org/elasticsearch/plugins/PluginsService.java:113:in `<init>'
        from org/elasticsearch/node/Node.java:144:in `<init>'
        from org/elasticsearch/node/NodeBuilder.java:145:in `build'
        from spamdetection/SpamDetection.java:63:in `client'
        from spamdetection/SpamDetection.java:30:in `SpammerDetector'
        from java/lang/reflect/Method.java:497:in `invoke'
        from spam.rb:53:in `(root)'
        from spam.rb:53:in `(root)'
Caused by:
JarHell.java:120:in `parseClassPath': java.lang.IllegalStateException: Classpath should not contain empty elements! (outdated shell script from a previous version?) classpath=''
        from JarHell.java:95:in `parseClassPath'
        from PluginsService.java:338:in `loadBundles'
        from PluginsService.java:113:in `<init>'
        from Node.java:144:in `<init>'
        from NodeBuilder.java:145:in `build'
        from SpamDetection.java:63:in `client'
        from SpamDetection.java:30:in `SpammerDetector'
        from NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-2:in `invoke0'
        from NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62:in `invoke'
        from DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43:in `invoke'
        from Method.java:497:in `invoke'
        from JavaMethod.java:451:in `invokeDirectWithExceptionHandling'
        from JavaMethod.java:312:in `invokeDirect'
        from InstanceMethodInvoker.java:45:in `call'
        from CachingCallSite.java:326:in `cacheAndCall'
        from CachingCallSite.java:170:in `call'
        from spam.rb:53:in `__file__'
        from spam.rb:-1:in `load'
        from Ruby.java:857:in `runScript'
        from Ruby.java:850:in `runScript'
        from Ruby.java:729:in `runNormally'
        from Ruby.java:578:in `runFromMain'
        from Main.java:395:in `doRunFromMain'
        from Main.java:290:in `internalRun'
        from Main.java:217:in `run'
        from Main.java:197:in `main'
```

When trying to call my Java JAR file from JRuby. What's causing this error?

Comment: I'm getting the same problem while running tests and it is simply not possible to remove the duplicate jars in my case - many trasitive dependencies. Just wondering if there is any other solution to this problem  other than modifying the elasticsearch code ? Please see the issue here: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/14348.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can now [disable](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/16174) the "jar hell" check during tests via the `tests.jarhell.check` property.

Comment: Can you please let me know how to set this.  i added this test {
    systemProperties = System.properties
    systemProperty 'tests.security.manager', 'false'
    systemProperty 'tests.jarhell.check', 'false'
} but still not working. Where to disable it

Comment: Disabling jarhell via settings only works until you try to load plugins - the PluginManager does not check this flag. You need to remove all plugin files from the embedded "home" dir. Then you can load plugins via classpath, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41298467/how-to-start. Otherwise plugins can only be loaded if jarhell is disabled via hacks like mentioned in the other answers.

Answer (score 17):

You can create a package named `org.elasticsearch.bootstrap` in your `src/test/java`, and put this class in there:

```
package org.elasticsearch.bootstrap;
import java.net.URL;
public class JarHell {
    private JarHell() {}
    public static void checkJarHell() throws Exception {}
    public static void checkJarHell(URL urls[]) throws Exception {}
    public static void checkVersionFormat(String targetVersion) {}
    public static void checkJavaVersion(String resource, String targetVersion) {}
    public static URL[] parseClassPath() {return new URL[]{};}
}
```

This has the advantage that the production code that uses the node builder to initialize the node can stay clean of any hacks, jar hell check is disabled only in the unit tests.

Comment: Uff. I had this error once in a while, and the solution I had tried were all a mess. This works like a charm! Thanks

Comment: In ES5.6, the signature of function `parseClassPath()` has changed. So, new one should be `public static Set<URL> parseClassPath() {return ImmutableSet.of();}`

Answer (score 3):

If you are getting "jar hell" error while running unit tests, following hack should take care of it - agree that it's not an elegant way.

```
String originalClassPath = System.getProperty("java.class.path");
  String[] classPathEntries = originalClassPath.split(";");
  StringBuilder esClasspath = new StringBuilder();
       for (String entry : classPathEntries) {
           if (entry.contains("elasticsearch") || entry.contains("lucene")) {
               esClasspath.append(entry);
               esClasspath.append(";");
           }
       }
  System.setProperty("java.class.path", esClasspath.toString());
  node = nodeBuilder().local(true).settings(settings).node();
  System.setProperty("java.class.path", originalClassPath);
```

Answer (score 3):

I am late, but I figured that my answer may help others in the future and that's why I am posting it.

I believe that the right solution is to find the root cause and exclude the library that is producing the jar hell rather than hiding the problem. For example, in my case, I had the following duplicated library :

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: jar hell!
class: org.hamcrest.BaseDescription
jar1: C:\Users\Yeikel\.m2\repository\org\hamcrest\hamcrest-all\1.3\hamcrest-all-1.3.jar
jar2: C:\Users\Yeikel\.m2\repository\org\hamcrest\hamcrest-core\1.3\hamcrest-core-1.3.jar
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.JarHell.checkClass(JarHell.java:275)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.JarHell.checkJarHell(JarHell.java:192)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.JarHell.checkJarHell(JarHell.java:89)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.BootstrapForTesting.<clinit>(BootstrapForTesting.java:90)
```

All I did to fix the problem is to find the duplication and exclude it from my libraries. In this case, the library was bundled with JUnit as well

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since elasticsearch 7.14.0 `JarHell` class has been moved to `org.elasticsearch.jdk` package. To disable jar hell checking in Elasticsearch versions >= 7.14 just create below class in `org.elasticsearch.jdk` package.

```
package org.elasticsearch.jdk;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.function.Consumer;

public class JarHell {
    private JarHell() {}

    public static void checkJarHell(Set<URL> urls, Consumer<String> output) throws Exception {}

    public static void checkJarHell(Consumer<String> output) {}

    public static void checkVersionFormat(String targetVersion) {}

    public static void checkJavaVersion(String resource, String targetVersion) {}

    public static Set<URL> parseClassPath() {
        return new HashSet<>();
    }

    static Set<URL> parseClassPath(String classPath) {
        return new HashSet<>();
    }
}
```