# How to start elasticsearch 5.1 embedded in my java application?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

With elasticsearch 2.x I used the following code to launch an embedded Node for testing:

```
@Bean
public Node elasticSearchTestNode() {
    return NodeBuilder.nodeBuilder()
            .settings(Settings.settingsBuilder()
                    .put("http.enabled", "true")
                    .put("path.home", "elasticsearch-data")
                    .build())
            .node();
}
```

This does not compile any more. How can I start an embedded node in 5.x ?

Comment: "This does not compile any more" What compilation error do you get?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Embedding elasticsearch is no longer officially supported, and it's a bit more complicated than in 2.x, but it works.

You need to add some dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
        <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency><!-- required by elasticsearch -->
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch.plugin</groupId>
        <artifactId>transport-netty4-client</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency><!-- required by elasticsearch -->
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
    </dependency>
```

And then launch a node like this:

```
@Bean
public Node elasticSearchTestNode() throws NodeValidationException {
    Node node = new MyNode(
            Settings.builder()
                    .put("transport.type", "netty4")
                    .put("http.type", "netty4")
                    .put("http.enabled", "true")
                    .put("path.home", "elasticsearch-data")
                    .build(),
            asList(Netty4Plugin.class));
    node.start();
    return node;
}

private static class MyNode extends Node {
    public MyNode(Settings preparedSettings, Collection<Class<? extends Plugin>> classpathPlugins) {
        super(InternalSettingsPreparer.prepareEnvironment(preparedSettings, null), classpathPlugins);
    }
}
```

Comment: That helped a bit. Now i get `java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to obtain node locks, tried [[target/elasticsearch]] with lock id [0]; maybe these locations are not writable or multiple nodes were started without increasing [node.max_local_storage_nodes] (was [1])`

Comment: you could try to delete you data folder if that's somehow f***ed up

Comment: Do you have any idea what I get , `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error finding the build shortHash. Stopping Elasticsearch now so it doesn't run in subtly broken ways. This is likely a build bug.`?. I am using version `5.2.2` btw.

Comment: @AhmetDAL I haven't tried it yet with 5.2.2, as our main search project still runs on ES 2.4 at the moment. If you get it working please edit my answer :)

Comment: dependency cannot be found!!

Answer (score 11):

The simplest way to make ES5 working is to use [Allegro `embedded-elasticsearch` library](https://github.com/allegro/embedded-elasticsearch) (more info in article [here](https://allegro.tech/2016/09/embedded-elasticsearch.html)). After day of struggling with embedding ES5 on jar level I found it pretty easy. Include into your pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>pl.allegro.tech</groupId>
    <artifactId>embedded-elasticsearch</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

and use following code in your unit test

```
EmbeddedElastic embeddedElastic = EmbeddedElastic.builder()
        .withElasticVersion("5.5.2")
        .withSetting(PopularProperties.HTTP_PORT, 21121)
        .build();
embeddedElastic.start();
```

Test will automatically download Elastic and run it in isolated environment driven from your test at OS process level. `http://localhost:21121` proves it works.

Our application has to interact with different versions of ESs. So this was another reason why this solution was also useful for our case, since we wouldn't otherwise be able to test multiple versions of ESs by adding multiple elasticsearch.jars into classpath.

Note: if this approach resembles "poor-man's Docker" to you, you can also have a look at [TestContainers](https://www.testcontainers.org/) project. I didn't try it myself though I suppose it would be possible, assuming your testing infrastructure have the use of Docker.

Comment: Nice approach. Works out of the box for me. The only drawback is that it launches a second JVM which consumes more memory than doing it in-process.

Comment: @Tomas this is what exactly i am searching for, i am able to start the elasticsearch instance, can you please guide me how to load a file/data and how to search that data back based on Key ? I am new to ES.

Comment: @Prajitha ES has powerful REST API, see manual https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index.html . You can communicate with spawned ES on localhost url as I wrote above.

Comment: @TomášZáluský Thanks for this answer. You saved my day!

Comment: Agreed about TestContainers. I pushed that sometime ago: https://www.testcontainers.org/modules/elasticsearch/. That said, I prefer using docker fabric8 maven plugin instead. See for example this project: https://github.com/dadoonet/elasticsearch-beyonder/blob/master/pom.xml

Comment: dependency cannot be found!!

Answer (score 5):

It's not supported.

You should read [this blog post](https://www.elastic.co/blog/elasticsearch-the-server).

EDIT:

This is how I solved the [integration tests with maven](http://david.pilato.fr/blog/2016/10/18/elasticsearch-real-integration-tests-updated-for-ga/) problem.

Comment: OK, it's certainly not a good idea to embed elasticsearch in production, but I still need it for testing.

Comment: I updated my answer with http://david.pilato.fr/blog/2016/10/18/elasticsearch-real-integration-tests-updated-for-ga/

Comment: You might consider embeding the relevant parts from the links you provided in your answer. Links come and go and there aren't many things more frustrating than having found an answer to a question you've been stuck with for hours just to discover that the links in it are dead:) https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers

Comment: If you use Maven and don't want to use an Ant script you can also use the Elasticsearch Maven Plugin to run instances of Elasticsearch version 5+ during the integration test phase of a build: https://github.com/alexcojocaru/elasticsearch-maven-plugin

Answer (score 0):

Embedded elasticsearch is not supported anymore

You can use this maven dependency, it will start elasticsearch 6 cluster for you

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.elasticsearch-6</groupId>
     <artifactId>elasticsearch-embedded-cluster</artifactId>
     <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

You can read more details on 
https://github.com/nitishgoyal13/elasticsearch-6-embedded-cluster