# How to run elasticsearch 5.1 server from within Java application (not through command line)

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

In elasticsearch 1.x, I used to call:

```
org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(args)
```

But in 5.x, they made the class org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch package-private (default), so I am not able to run the ES server from java code in a neat way anymore. Is there any alternative neat way to do it (something different than Runtime exec or Apache Commons Exec)?

Thank you!

Comment: I found this here, maybe that helps you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41298467/how-to-start-elasticsearch-5-1-embedded-in-my-java-application/41299436#41299436

Answer (score 1):

You can not. It's not supported.

See https://www.elastic.co/blog/elasticsearch-the-server

> **Embedded Elasticsearch not supported**
>
> Some users run Elasticsearch as embedded. We are not going to stop them from doing so, but we cannot support it. Embedding Elasticsearch bypasses the security manager, the Jar Hell checks, the bootstrap checks, and plugin loading. It is inherently unsafe and not recommended for production. For the sanity of our developers and support team, we cannot support users who disable all of the safety mechanisms which we have added for good reasons. For the same reason, we will not accept pull requests or make changes specifically to support the embedded use case

Comment: "Not supported" by Elastic, the company, but that page does say they are not going to "stop someone from doing it".

Comment: Yeah. What would be interesting IMO is to understand what is the problem @xProgramery is trying to solve here. May be the answer could be something else. :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for reply. As they mentioned, it's not supported neither recommended. However, if you must, you can create a package in your application:
org.elasticsearch.bootstrap

And then copy/paste in the package the Elasticsearch class from source:
 https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/5.1/core/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/bootstrap/Elasticsearch.java

Then from your application, you can call the main method and pass your arguments to it:
ElasticsearchLauncher.main(args);