# Migrating from Elastic 2 to 5

Tags: elasticsearch

1)We have used the NodeBuilder from the previous version of ES to create in memory nodes on demand.

2) With Elastic 5, as Nodebuilder is not available, we are using below code:

```
   File tmpDir = File.createTempFile("elastic",Long.toString(System.nanoTime()));
    Settings settings = Settings.builder()
            .put("http.enabled", true)
              .put("index.number_of_shards", "1")
              .put("path.data", new File(tmpDir, "data").getAbsolutePath())
              .put("path.logs", new File(tmpDir, "logs").getAbsolutePath())
              .put("path.work", new File(tmpDir, "work").getAbsolutePath()) 
              .put("transport.tcp.port", "9300")
              .put("network.host", "localhost")              
              .put("node.data", "true")
              .put("node.master", "true")

             .put("path.home", tmpDir)
            .put("transport.type", "local").build();
    return new ElasticsearchTemplate(new Node(settings).start().client());
```

3) When we try to access the ElasticsearchRepository, it is giving below exception:

```
NoNodeAvailableException[None of the configured nodes are available: [{#transport#-1}{6gkUXEX6Rsyowd928D0k_A}{localhost}{127.0.0.1:9200}]]
        at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.ensureNodesAreAvailable(TransportClientNodesService.java:347)
        at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.execute(TransportClientNodesService.java:245)
        at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportProxyClient.execute(TransportProxyClient.java:59)
        at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient.doExecute(TransportClient.java:363)
        at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractClient.execute(AbstractClient.java:408)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequestBuilder.execute(ActionRequestBuilder.java:80)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequestBuilder.execute(ActionRequestBuilder.java:54)
        at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchTemplate.doCount(ElasticsearchTemplate.java:495)
        at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchTemplate.count(ElasticsearchTemplate.java:473)
        at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.AbstractElasticsearchRepository.count(AbstractElasticsearchRepository.java:150)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:377)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:200)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:641)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:605)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:590)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
        at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:59)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy139.count(Unknown Source)
        at com.werner.ecp.elastic.service.carrier.ElasticCarrierServiceImpl.getCarrierCount(ElasticCarrierServiceImpl.java:58)
        at com.werner.ecp.elastic.service.carrier.ElasticCarrierServiceImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$e96152a4.invoke(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
```

4) Any thoughts on what am missing?  appreciate your help!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In recent versions you´ll be not be able to spawn a in memory node, nor use the TransportClient as it´s deprecated: consider using the "[Java High Level Client](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/master/java-rest-high.html#java-rest-high)" ASAP

The node you spawned tries to join a remote cluster/node and finds nothing because there is no elasticsearch running on your localhost

Do yourself and your project a favor and switch to the mentioned RestClient.

If you need or want to stick with the current approach see

[How to start elasticsearch 5.1 embedded in my java application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41298467/how-to-start-elasticsearch-5-1-embedded-in-my-java-application)

OR

https://github.com/allegro/embedded-elasticsearch

Here is some background information:

https://www.elastic.co/blog/state-of-the-official-elasticsearch-java-clients
https://www.elastic.co/blog/the-elasticsearch-java-high-level-rest-client-is-out

cheers