# How to test Elasticsearch without any possible harm for data?

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to test functionality of project which is built on elasticsearch. I already  have lots of data stored in the db. But i want somehow to test it without any possible harm. Is there any possible way or technology(which works like h2 f.e) to do it.

Answer (score 0):

H2 is a in memory database, also embeddable in your application. In the past versions of ES there was a option to bootstrap a embedded elasticsearch node with your application.

In the current version this feature is not available anymore. So you'll need to bring up at least one node using a second machine, VM or container running elasticsearch. At least running elsticsearch on your machine is still a option.

But maybe you're still on a old version of elasticsearch? Then have a look on this SO (assuming you're using java): [How to start elasticsearch 5.1 embedded in my java application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41298467/how-to-start-elasticsearch-5-1-embedded-in-my-java-application)