# Error on starting Elastic Transport client - Unsupported transport.type [netty4]

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-7

I'm migrating code from elastic 5 to 7

Elastic dependency in pom :

```
 <elastic.version>7.12.1</elastic.version>

 <dependency>
  <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
  <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
  <version>${elastic.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
  <artifactId>transport</artifactId>
  <version>${elastic.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
  <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client</artifactId>
  <version>${elastic.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

The client init looks like this:

```
val settings = Settings.builder()
  .put("cluster.name", cluster)
  .put("client.transport.sniff", true)
  .build()

val clientBase:TransportClient = new PreBuiltTransportClient(settings)
val client = hosts.foldLeft(clientBase)((c,h) =>
  c.addTransportAddress(new TransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName(h), port))
)
```

When Running the code getting the following error:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unsupported transport.type [netty4]
at org.elasticsearch.common.network.NetworkModule.getTransportSupplier(NetworkModule.java:201)
at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient.buildTemplate(TransportClient.java:186)
at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient.<init>(TransportClient.java:282)
at org.elasticsearch.transport.client.PreBuiltTransportClient.<init>(PreBuiltTransportClient.java:119)
at org.elasticsearch.transport.client.PreBuiltTransportClient.<init>(PreBuiltTransportClient.java:105)
at org.elasticsearch.transport.client.PreBuiltTransportClient.<init>(PreBuiltTransportClient.java:95)
```

Please advise how to fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to add `transport-netty4-client` as a dependency, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41298467/how-to-start-elasticsearch-5-1-embedded-in-my-java-application/41299436#41299436)